# number of templated parameters in a boost::tuple

Tags: c++, tuples, boost-tuples

I am using `boost::tuple` for my code.

Suppose that I want to store an equivalent of a structure having 3 members

```
  typedef boost::tuple< std::string, int, double > my_struct;
```

Is there any way of method to call on the `tuple` that will give me the number of members contained so in this case 3?

My goal here is to monitor when I increase the number of template parameters.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on "monitor increase the number of template parameters"? What sense is this going to make? You can only increase the number of parameters at compile time and if you pass a tuple around as `tuple<T...>` or `T` you will have to "loop" over it anyway.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but in C++11 `std::tuple_size<tuple>::value` gives the number of parameters of an `std::tuple`.

Comment: pmr: Want to realize when I switch from tuple<A,B> to tuple<A,B,C>. I basically want to always assert this condition in some point of my code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `::boost::tuples::length<T>::value` helper function.

See [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_advanced_interface.html).

Answer (score 3):

Check the doccumentation [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_advanced_interface.html).

```
length<T>::value
```

gives the length of the tuple type T.

Answer (score 2):

According to [boost::tuple documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_advanced_interface.html) what you are looking for is `length<T>::value`